# Upload not saving large files

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to create an upload form but it wont save large files and doesn't give any errors either.

I don't know where exactly the limit is but a 65kb image saves fine, whereas a 4mb image does not.  The uploads folder is simply empty for larger files.  I can verify it's uploading and see the request sent...however the server uploads folder remains empty.

Here is my upload script:

```
<?php
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; 
$storeFolder = 'uploads';  
if (!empty($_FILES)) { 
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];               
    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  
    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];  
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);    
}
?>
```

And here are the relevant settings I have in my php.ini:

```
max_input_time = -1
memory_limit = 1500M
post_max_size = 1500M
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 1500M
max_file_uploads = 100
allow_url_fopen = On
```

This is for internal use only if you're wondering about the odd settings.  As far as my actual upload page, it's just a simple html snipped from W3 schools.

This is running on Apache on an Ubuntu server.  The script seems to work fine in a Windows WAMP setup.  Also, the permissions on the directory are correct.

Comment: `upload_max_filesize = 1500M` ? and you trust W3schools ? Try to use upload libraries e.g. swfupload instead of `<input type="file">` for large file.

Comment: 1) http://www.w3fools.com   2) Have you restarted your server `/etc/init.d apache2 restart` after making changes to your php.ini

Comment: Daryl...I feel like an idiot.  Yeah, restarting the server resolved the issue.  Thank you

Comment: As far as the W3's comment...im actually using dropzone.js, I just mentioned the W3 schools to make it simpler, its the same concept anyways.

Comment: @johnhannigan I will submit this as an answer since this resolved your issue

Comment: 6 more minutes until I can make it the answer.

Comment: @johnhannigan as a sidenote, you shouldn't set the php.ini to such large values, as this may flood your web server (if the script mis-used by hackers) and it will cause browser to timeout.

Comment: Shivan thanks for the info - this is actually to be used internally amongst a group of 10 computers that have no internet access.  It's just for testing purposes for some other work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After editing your php.ini you must reload/restart your apache server to make all changes take place. Issue from Command line one of the following:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart 
service apache2 restart
```

OR

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
service apache2 reload
```

Either one of the 4 will be be fine; preferably the restart option